# How to read in csv files with quotes as text qualifiers and not touch NAN values?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I have some csv files I want to read into python which combine several dificulties, that make it impossible to read in properly so far:

- The separator is comma: ","
- They include different NAN values like *-inf* values that Pandas
  read_csv interpretes as NAN values, but I need them literally and
  unchanged.
- Using numpy genfromtxt does not work however, since I have columns with text qualifiers and comma inside, which is the delimiter (e.g. "Doe, John")

What can I do to import this anyways, leaving the data as untouched as possible?
My goal is to try to convert each value to float and catch the errors, so that I see what kind of non convertable data is present in the file.

Comment: Sorry you want the string `-inf` rather than `np.inf`? Are the inf values for a specific column or throughout the csv? You can specify which values to treat as `NaN` by passing param `na_values` with values to treat as `NaN` and then `default_na=False` see the docs:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv

Comment: The problem is, that I have no idea what kind of na_values I will find. There seem to be a broad variety. -inf is only one of them. I want to search for them as soon as loaded into python to decide how to handle them.

Comment: but you should have an idea what values that you want to treat as `NaN` though? From the list `‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘nan’` so you can pick the ones from this and then leave the others to come through without converting

Comment: Ok  that is a good idea. I will try on that.

Comment: `genfromtxt` accepts any iterable that gives it lines (including a list of lines).  So you can open the file, read and cleanup each line and pass it on. Or `readlines` and edit the whole thing.  Another option is to use the `csv` module reader can handle the quotes.